# Any way to put an if statement in the function call argument?

Tags: python

I found out that we can use the ternary op inside the function call argument:

```py
def foo(n):
    print(n)
```

```py
a, b = 1, 2
foo(a if a>b else b)
# prints 2
```

I wonder is there a way to use if without the else in the function call argument? so something like if it's true, pass a to it, if not, don't pass anything.

I've tried

```py
foo(a if a>b else pass)
foo(a if a>b)
foo(if a>b: a)
foo(a>b and a)
```

None of the above works.

Thanks for your help.

Edit-----

Sorry, let me rephrase my question.

What I'm asking for is a way to determine whether I should pass the argument based on a condition.

So basically I have to call a big function that takes a lot of kwargs, say:

```py
# function call
thefunc(
    a=1,
    b=2,
    c=3,
    d=4,
    e=5
    #...
)
```

And all of the args are options which its up to me, or in some cases, a condition.

Since the argument list is so big that writing function calls inside the if statement is not preferred, so I need to know is there a way to, say:

```py
thefunc(
    a=1,
    #if condition: b=2,
    c=3,
    ....
)
```

So to determine whether to give the kwarg or not. Its okay if there isn't, just need to know, thanks.

Comment: Why not `foo(max(a, b))`?

Comment: no. just write the if statement and pass 1 or 2 args accordingly inside the if statement. The ternary op is guaranteeing a "response" for one slot, be it under `if` or under `else`.

Comment: `foo(a if a>b else None)`; `pass` is a [*statement*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement), not a value.

Comment: But why not evaluate the conditioanl outside and pass the value to the function

Comment: The thing is I have a very big function that take a lot of kwargs, and I need to decide whether to put some of the specific kwargs based on some condition inside the function argument since the argument list is too long to write it again. I'll try @jonrsharpe 's solution, thanks a lot.

Comment: That suggests you have other code smells, e.g. https://refactoring.guru/smells/long-parameter-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can if you don't mind some ugliness... The * syntax turns a list of values into parameters, so you could use:

```
foo(*[a] if a > b else [])
```

Whether you *should* is something else :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator needs both if- and else- substatements. Instead of trying to use only-if, you can use default function arguments:

```
def foo(n=None):
```

Pass `None` to the function, if needed:

`foo(a if a > b else None)`

And check inside for the `None` - non-`None` argument:

```
def foo(n=None):
    if n:
        print(n)
```

Comment: Strictly, `if n is not None:`; there are other false-y values.